# Trying to remove redundant lines from compare

Tags: beyondcompare

Here are a couple of lines on my compare

```
                           Cycle Date - 03/22/2022
                           Cycle Date - 03/23/2022


Policy Number : 9999999999                              Produced on 03/23/2022
Policy Number : 9999999999                              Produced on 03/22/2022
```

I do not want these lines to show when I click on Diffs

I tried these in Rules, Unimportant Data

```
^\s*Cycle Date - \d{2}+/\d{2}+/\d{4}
^*\sProduced on \d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}
```

It's not easy to get the right combinations or whether it can be done. Not sure if it needs to be added in the Grammar section

NOTE - I have Everything Else box checked on Grammar Elements that are important to the comparison

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems with the regular expressions.

```
^\s*Cycle Date - \d{2}+/\d{2}+/\d{4}
```

With `\d{2}` you catch two digits, so there is no need of a `+`

Try:

```
^\s*Cycle Date - \d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}
```

In (I guess the `*\s` should be a `\s*)

```
^\s*Produced on \d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}
```

you select for a line (`^` = start of line) with leading spaces, then the `Produced by...`. But the line starts with `Policy`.

If you remove the `^`,

```
\sProduced on \d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}
```

then you get what you want:

[image: Comparison]

[image: Importance rules]

Comment: I tried the changes and it still doesn't get rid of the lines.  I want to make sure of some things.  After adding the lines in Unimportant test, I click on the Minor button.